# django - keras - aws elastic beanstalk - Updating data for deployed app

Tags: django, amazon-s3, deployment, keras, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

### Background

I am on a mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.5.
There does not seem to be any literature on here referring to this specific problem  with the measure of intricacies I am finding. This involves the simple deployment of a django application. `pythonanywhere` will deploy it, but is incredibly slow.
I have a large model (.hd5) file generated from a deep net in `keras`. This is about `1.5 GB` in size. My entire project is about `1.77 GB`. I have the entire project working perfectly, with generalized code (e.g., using os.path.join instead of relative references) and everything kosher with the django documentation. This is what fuels my search engine in my application, without this, the entire site is not worth deploying, as all `d3.js` charts populate from its data returned. This same problem occured on `pythonanywhere.com`, after purchasing their extended package to store 5GB, the site ran too slow to even make it worth it. Be mindful, this is lightning fast on my local machine (after about 30 seconds of load time before the 127.0.0.1:8080 pop up as valid to go visit and test). Granted, this was a flask prototype and I have ported all code to django now, as django seems to be easier to deploy.

### Problem

I have gone through[this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html) entire tutorial, from front to back, with military precision and I have not had any errors running locally. This is [image: my django project] after running `python startproject dwsite`. I continued to build an app within this which I named `deepwisdom` as you see in the subfolder. Static and templates files are references in this directory, its basically just a bunch of bootstrap code files sitting there. However, there is a rather large `1.5 GB` data folder that my project requires to operate. This has the model object and some small pickles I load before the app starts to reference bible verses and content. I have a small `bible.db sqlite database` inside of there as well. Long story short, no problems at all rendering or executing my search functionality locally, but I cannot upload my entire application due to the upper limit AWS has put on EB apps (150MB).

### After deployed

The last few lines of the tutorial were a success,
[image: as shown here] in the successful deployment of the app. They have spun me up an s3 bucket named:

`elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-281685280576`

and they have spun me up a CNAME named:

```
django-env.mm9prjibak.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com
```

I immediately change my dwtest/dwtest.setting.py file to reflect this, and then go to visit the site, and get exactly what I expected, [image: a missing data folder error] a missing data file from my missing data folder that I could not upload in sync with my app.

## My (pending success/failure) solution

So within my s3 instance I have the folder created from the eb cli named dwtest/app-181223_161536.zip

This is exactly what I expected, however **this does not contain my data folder from the previous image**, as it would not let me upload it previously, giving me [image: this error] this error.

Okay so I actually deleted that zip folder that was[image: sitting in here] with the zipped up version of the folder on my desktop; the deployed app version. As you can see it is now gone and I am re-uploading the exact same zip file, unzipped, with the data folder placed within it, rezipped, and being uploaded. This upload is taking forever, so I have not tested whether it will work, however I presume I will need to do some type of a `eb update` or  `eb update-environment --application-name dwsite` seems to feel right from the documentation, but I have no idea. Odds are, this won't work as when it asks me to do a fresh `deploy` it references my desktop folder I `cd dwsite`. As nothing I have tried for the last week has worked. If nobody knows what to do with this situation, bottom line, I have a perfectly fine working django application locally, and I officially have no idea how to upload it, however I feel *very* close.

If you took the time to read this post that is the fruit of my frustration over the last 5 days, thank you, even if you can't help, I feel comfort knowing I am at least acknowledged by someone, unlike the technical support teams from any of these PaaS companies.

Very respectfully,
bmc

## EDIT:

Is this the solution? From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47715606/how-to-deploy-to-ec2-instance-from-a-zip-file-in-s3)?

```
aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --application-name <your-app-name>  --
environment-name <environment-name-to-deploy>   --version-label <version-
label-to-deploy>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to separate your data from your application and deploy it separately.  You can do this with beanstalk by zipping your data, creating an s3 bucket, and then uploading the zip to that s3 bucket.  [Then, you can write an eb command to download the data to a location of your choosing on your server at deploy time](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-files).  That way your code bundle stays smaller than the beanstalk limit (it also uploads to eb faster).  The s3 download to the server will be extremely fast if you are using a vpc to s3 gateway.  n.b., this method will have every server having its own copy of the data.  If you want your servers to share data, use AWS EFS.

Comment: so I've got my data sitting in an s3 bucket that is referenced from my eb environment and application, how do I tell aws to `update` with my new zip file I have sitting in there? I tried `aws elasticbeanstalk update-application --application-name dwsite --region us-east-1` but that just gave me an echo of a config file which made no sense to me.

Comment: If you've added a copy down step, you can just rerun [`eb deploy`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-deploy.html).  That will kick off a new deploy and will then execute your custom command to pull in the new s3 data.